# Unity - custom struct name in inspector based on struct' filed(s)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, serialization, struct

I have a custom serializable struct stored in as a list elements.
When only one field of a struct is public

```
[System.Serializable]
public struct MemoryMoment {
    float Importance;   //Subjective
    Person who;
    Room where;
    string when;
    string what;
    //string why;
    public string Descr;

    public MemoryMoment (float importance, Person who, Room where, string when, string what) {
        this.Importance = importance;
        this.who = who;
        this.where = where;
        this.when = when;
        this.what = what;
        //this.why = "UNUSED";
        this.Descr = where.Type.ToString () + " " + when + ", " + who.Name + " " + what;
    }
}
```

then this whole struct is named in inspector after that element[image]

but when more than one field in struct is public

```
[System.Serializable]
public struct MemoryMoment {
    public float Importance;    //Subjective
    Person who;
    Room where;
    string when;
    string what;
    //string why;
    public string Descr;

    public MemoryMoment (float importance, Person who, Room where, string when, string what) {
        this.Importance = importance;
        this.who = who;
        this.where = where;
        this.when = when;
        this.what = what;
        //this.why = "UNUSED";
        this.Descr = where.Type.ToString () + " " + when + ", " + who.Name + " " + what;
    }
}
```

then the struct is named just "Element N"[image]

**How can I provide custom inspector name for my struct?**

I.e. something like this:

```
[NameInInspector]
string n = "(" + Importance.ToString() + ") " + Descr;
```

Comment: Screenshots are not accepted on SO, include your code as text.

Comment: Edited. Code instead of screenshoots.

Comment: Have you tried to create a custom inspector?

Comment: Tried PropertyDrawer but it only works for classes

Comment: I don't see the reason for those two downvotes, OP corrected immediately by posting the code instead of screenshots.

Comment: @Galandil I noticed the down-vote too and gave OP and upvote. I think the down-voter are from C# users who don't understand the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's caused by how Unity serializes the `MemoryMoment` struct.

Basically, if there's a `string` as the first declared field in the struct, then Unity will use its content to "name" the Element of the list.

So, if you want to read the content of `Descr` instead of `Element X` you just need to move the declaration `public string Descr;` on top of all declarations:

```
[System.Serializable]
public struct MemoryMoment {
    public string Descr;
    public float Importance;    //Subjective
    Person who;
    Room where;
    string when;
    string what;
    //string why;

    public MemoryMoment (float importance, Person who, Room where, string when, string what) {
        this.Importance = importance;
        this.who = who;
        this.where = where;
        this.when = when;
        this.what = what;
        //this.why = "UNUSED";
        this.Descr = where.Type.ToString () + " " + when + ", " + who.Name + " " + what;
    }
}
```